# What does this operator mean in C?

Tags: c, struct, operator-keyword

I've the following code snippet:

```
for(int i=0;i<6; i++)  rtk->rb[i]=i<3?opt->rb[i]:0.0;
```

I can't understand the meaning of this line...rtk is a struct that has a field named rb (which is an array) and opt is another struct, which also has a the same field rb... the simbols < and ? are confusing me... rtk type is `rtk_t`, while opt type is `prcopt_t`:

```
typedef struct {        
    
    double rb[6];       /* base position/velocity (ecef) (m|m/s) */
    ....
} rtk_t;

typedef struct {        

    double rb[3];       /* base position for relative mode {x,y,z} (ecef) (m) */
    
} prcopt_t;
```

Comment: Maybe some parentheses and spacing helps? `rtk->rb[i] = (i < 3) ? opt->rb[i] : 0.0;`

Comment: If you look through your C text-books, what do they say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the right part of this  here :

```
rtk->rb[i]=i<3?opt->rb[i]:0.0;
```

i.e.

```
i<3?opt->rb[i]:0.0
```

is another way to say:

```
 if (i < 3)
 {
     x = opt->rb[i];
 }
 else
 {
     x = 0.0;
 }
```

only that the way you wrote it is using `ternary operators`